# Can I use bootstrap results at the observation level?

Tags: regression, bootstrap, standard-error

I have read quite a bit of bootstrapping, but the issue I want to address seem not to appear.

Consider a simple regression model:

$$ y_{i} =  \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{i} + e_{i}$$

I am aware that bootstrapping is quite useful for obtaining standard error of estimated coefficients $\hat{\beta_{0}}$ and $\hat{\beta_{1}}$, and for other statistics of the regression. But my interests lays in the predicted errors $\hat{e_{i}}$. Every bootstrap iteration generates a set of $\hat{e_{i}}$. Thus, for each unit of observation $i$, I have $M$ values of $\hat{e_{i}}$.

Can I use these $M$ values to obtain a standard error for $\hat{e_{i}}$ **for each $i$**? This would be very useful, for example, to identify units with high standard errors, which might be an indication of measurement errors or coding errors, etc. But there are other uses too.

Intuitively, this seems possible to me, but I want to confirm this makes sense theoretically.

Comment: I do this all the time by training on bootstrap samples and scoring on a hold out set.  It's useful to make a plot where you sort the test set by predicted value (from a model trained on the full training set) and then display bootstrapped intervals.  So yah, good idea, do it : )

Comment: Haha. I don't want to sound rude but, besides the fact that you use it, is there a more formal justification?

Comment: No offense taken, fair enough.  I think the justification is the same in bootstrapping any statistic.  There is a thing you are trying to estimate $p (y_i)$, training a model on some set $T$ gives you a point estimate $\hat y_i$ of this value, and bootstrapping gives you an approximation of the distribution of $\hat y_i$ over the sampling distribution of various training sets.

Comment: Well, I've just done so, and it is beautiful! Any suggestion on the number of replications?

Comment: It depends on the size of your data and how much patience you can tolerate.

Comment: It's a panel data model with $T=5$, so the $\hat{e_{i}}$ is estimated with only five datapoints. :/

Comment: What conditions are known about your $e_i$? Are they, for instance, IID? Or do they follow a known covariance structure, e.g. autoregressive or compound symmetric? If we are completely agnostic about $e_i$ then we are out of options and cannot, in fact, pull ourselves up by our bootstraps.

Comment: As @AdamO said, I think the assumption about $e_i$ should be considered. In the case of assuming IID, I guess we can say that the estimates of error $\hat e_i =y_i-\hat \beta_0-\hat \beta_1 x_i$ where the coefficients are regressed from the original data has the normal distribution with mean 0 and sd $\sigma$. Then, I would say we might use these $\hat e_i$s to construct the empirical distribution of error and bootstrap them to calculate the sample standard deviation.